# ¿Cómo se llama a la persona que maneja marionetas?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Lo mas parecido que se me ocurre es *titiritero*, pero hay una diferencia bastante grande entre un títere y una marioneta.

Me parece curioso ya que existe la frase hecha "el que tira de los hilos" que claramente se refiere a una persona manejando los "hilos" de una marioneta, pero no consigo encontrar un sustantivo para tal persona.

Comment: Que diferencia hay entre una [marioneta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OQkq7DJ) y un títere? **`marioneta`** `1. f. títere (‖ muñeco movido por hilos u otro procedimiento).`

Comment: @ukemi hmm, tiene sentido lo que preguntas, siempre habia entendido como marioneta los muñecos que se controlan con cuerdas y títeres a los que se controlan metiendo la mano dentro. Aunque ahora que lo pienso igual si que son sinónimos en su totalidad...

Comment: Curioso, yo siempre pensé que era justo lo contrario aunque por lo visto son sinónimos

Comment: Una vez aclarado que títere y marioneta son sinónimos, si quieres un sustantivo específico para la palabra "marioneta", ¿qué tal "marionetista"? http://dle.rae.es/?id=OQlHEbg

Comment: @RubioRic esa la iba aponer como respuesta, pero como te has adelantado, por favor, transforma este comentario en respuesta. Brian, si lo encuentro pongo un enlace al video. En la primera película de Hellboy alguien dice algo así como "veo la marioneta, pero dónde está el marionetista?" que debe ser una traducción de "I see the **puppet**, but where is the **puppeteer**?"

Comment: @Diego Ok, es que no tenía claro si la pregunta seguía en pie despues de lo de títere = marioneta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pues el D.R.A.E contiene la palabra exacta que estás buscando: **marionetista**.

[**marionetista**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OQlHEbg)

> 1. m. y f. **titiritero** (‖ persona que maneja los títeres).
> 2. m. y f. Constructor de marionetas.

Nótese que el diccionario no contempla esa distinción planteada en los comentarios entre una marioneta y un títere, y por tanto titiritero es sinónimo de marionetista.

Answer (score 0):

Marioneta y títere son diferentes, la marioneta se maneja con cuerdas y el títere está diseñado para introducir la mano. El último comentario es correcto en cuanto al término **marionetista** es el que propone la RAE. Sin embargo, la frase en inglés a la que se refiere probablemente es  "I see the puppet but where is the *puppet master*" que es el término normalmente usado en inglés, aunque la palabra *puppeteer* también es correcta.

Comment: I think the relevant English phrase is "pulling the strings".

Answer (score 0):

A la persona que maneja marionetas se le llama titiritero o marionetista. El término "titiritero" se utiliza principalmente en España y América Latina, mientras que "marionetista" es más común en Norteamérica.

El titiritero o marionetista es el encargado de manipular las marionetas para darles vida y movimiento, y hacer que las historias que cuentan cobren vida en el escenario. Esta persona debe tener habilidades en la manipulación de las marionetas, así como en la creación de guiones y la interpretación de personajes.

El trabajo de un titiritero o marionetista puede ser muy creativo y emocionante, y se puede realizar en una variedad de lugares, como teatros, festivales, escuelas y bibliotecas. Además, el titiritero o marionetista también puede hacer uso de otros elementos como títeres de sombras, títeres de guante y marionetas de hilo para crear una experiencia teatral completa para el público.